# Laravel pattern based filter

Tags: php, laravel-4, routes

I'm reading the Laravel documentation and it is saying that it is possible to add a pattern based filter to a route

```
Route::filter('admin', function()
{
    //
});

Route::when('admin/*', 'admin');
```

I want to know how to specify if the filter is executed before or after the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern filters are always called **before** and cannot be called **after** a routes execution.

You can see it being called [in the source (4.1.24)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.1.24/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1246) on GitHub.

A solution to this is to have all your admin routes inside a route group and apply the filter to the entire group.